# EL properties of nested entity in nested data table not shown by Netbeans intellisense

Tags: jsf-2, autocomplete, el, netbeans-7

Sorry for my english. I have some java plane clasess that referencing database object (I'm not using JPA or similar, simple pojo). the structure is very simple, some pojos that repreenting database entities (person class, car class and so on), jsf page that present data using primefaces datatable and managedBean for manipulate data and make it accesible to jsf page throught EL.
This example work well, when I write the jsf page the autocomplete code functionality of Netbeans works fine, if i write ...#{person.  netbeans show a dialog with properties defined in person class.
The problem appear when I add new pojo class named phones. this class contains type, number and notes properties for phones class. I modified Person class adding a field List PhonesList; My Persons class now have a new propeties that can contain one o more phone numbers.
In jsf page I write:

```
<h:form id="form_persondata">
        <p:dataTable id="tbl_person" value="#{personDAO.personsList}"
                 var="item1"
                 selectionMode="single"
                 rowKey="#{item1.id}"  
                 selection="#{personDAO.selected}"
                 resizableColumns="true">
            <p:ajax event="rowSelect" 
                update=":form_persondata:tbl_person"/>
            <p:column headerText="Nombre y Apellidos" >
            <p:outputLabel value="#{item1.name}"/>
            <br/>
            <p:outputLabel value=" #{item1.apellidos}"/>
            </p:column>

            <p:dataTable id="tbl_phones" value="#{item1.phonesList}"
                     var="item2" resizableColumns="true">
                <p:column headerText="Phone Type" >

                <h:outputText  value="#{item2.type}"/>

                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Numero">
                <p:outputLabel value="#{item2.phonenumber}"/>
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>

            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
        </h:form>
```

EL expresions in second datatble #{item2. not produces autocompletion code when I press dot key. If I write the correct propertie name (of course I know it), this compile and run well, only autocompletion not work in this level.
Is not possible to reference clasess into another clasess with EL lenguaje?

Sorry my terrible english, I work with netbeans 7.4, jsf 2.2, primefaces 3.5 and CDI using @Named conventions only in personDAO class, not in person or phone or car classes.

My PersonDAO class:

...

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class PersonDAO implements Serializable {

    DBCollection Table;

    List<Person> personsList;

    Person Selected;
```

My Person class (simple pojo):

```
public class Person{

private String nombre;
private String apellidos;
private List<Phones> phonesList;

... getters and setters
```

And my Phones class:

```
public class Phones{
private String phoneType;
private String phoneNumber;
```

... getters and setters

Some sugestions? Am I making something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is not much you can do about it, if you are 100% that everything is correct and your code is running is it should be then this is just an IDEs fault. Autocomplete is sometimes messy (especially with EL and JSPs) so you have to sometimes accept that IDE just won't do the hard typing work for you:)

Answer (score 0):

I read using @Named tag, you can see this class when you use el, but I tried writing @Named tag on Phones class and not working.
It'll be el or netbeans problem. Thanks.